# ¿Como eliminar columnas vacías de DataTable?

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de quitar columnas vacías de un DataTable, pero no lo he logrado, aquí pongo el código:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = dgvNomina.DataSource as DataTable;

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                if(row[col].ToString() == string.Empty)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Remove(col);
                }   
            }
        }

        ImprimirGrid(dt);
```

pero cuando lo ejecuto me aparece este error:

> Colección modificada; puede que no se ejecute la operación de enumeración

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error te aparece porque estás eliminando un elemento de la colección `Columns` mientras estás dentro de la iteración. No puedes utilizar `foreach` para lograr eso, debes iterar en la colección de manera inversa, algo así:

```
for (int i = dt.Columns.Count; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if (row[dt.Columns[i]].ToString() == string.Empty)
  {
     dt.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
  }
}
```